# Edit User Details using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am stuck on editing user details and updating it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I click on "update" button, I can edit their name and email. And I can also delete the entry by clicking the "delete" button.

I have added the ability to add new User which I am able to code.

This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-browser-5ifrel?file=/src/User.js

How do I add a if-else statement in my render so that IF i click on "update" button on one of the entry (e.g., id === selected.id), it will transform the "name" and "email" to textboxes to allow for edit. And 2 buttons for them to "confirm" their update or "cancel" their update.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          this.state.users.map((u) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={u._id}>
              <div className="box">
                <h3>{u.name}</h3>
                <h4>{u.email}</h4>

                
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.beginEdit(u);
                  }}
                >Update
                </button>

                
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.deleteUser(u);
                  }}
                >Delete
                </button>

              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        {this.renderAddUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: it is called [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: The User.js file in the codesandbox is empty for me

Comment: hi apologies, i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use [conditional rendering](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/conditional-rendering).

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {
          this.state.users.map((u) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={u._id}>
              <div className="box">
                {u.isEditing ? (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="email" />
                  </React.Fragment>
                ) : (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <h3>{u.name}</h3>
                    <h4>{u.email}</h4>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}

                
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.beginEdit(u);
                  }}
                >Update
                </button>

                
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.deleteUser(u);
                  }}
                >Delete
                </button>

              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        {this.renderAddUser()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: what does u.isEditing? means

Comment: It's a boolean to indicate if the user is currently editing or not. Add it as a property to every user in state.users.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this that render output depends on the condition of  (id === selectedUser.id)

```
       state = {
         selected = null;
       }

       render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            {this.state.users.map((user) => {
              return (
                  <div className="box" >
                  {selected?.id === user?._id ? (
                  <>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="name" defaultValue={user.name} />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="email" defaultValue={user.email} />
                    <button onClick={() => { this.handleCancel(user);}}>
                       Cancel
                    </button>
    
                    
                    <button onClick={() => { this.handleConfirm(user);}}>
                      Confirm
                    </button>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <h3>{user.name}</h3>
                    <h4>{user.email}</h4>
    
                    <button onClick={() => { this.beginEdit(user);}}>
                       Update
                    </button>
    
                    
                    <button onClick={() => { this.deleteUser(user);}}>
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </>
                )}
                  </div>
              );
            })}
            {this.renderAddUser()}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: hi thanks, may i know why you put React.fragment below the div